# I stopped the server, but it pinged successfully, why?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ping, webserver

If I stop the apache server by `systemctl stop httpd` command, and if I ping it from command prompt (`ping [server’s IP address]`), it pinged successfully, why ? I was created the server on Google Cloud Platform and then I stopped the server by run this command on shell. But when I ping it, it pinged successfully, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply stopped the (Apache) service running on the (Google Cloud) server, not the server itself.

The ping demonstrated that the server is still running (and responding to pings). If you try to connect to port 80 then it should fail, confirming that the http service isn’t running.

Comment: To make it more explicit: Apache HTTPd is not involved with ICMP Echo Requests (“Ping”) at all.

Comment: Terminology here is important - the terms "server" and "service" can usually be used interchangeably when referring to a piece of software but not a physical machine. You stopped the apache *service*, but the physical *server* machine is still running.

Comment: @SamForbis but if I try to reach the server by paste the IP address (http://IP_Address) in browser after stop the server it shows that **This site can’t be reached**.

Comment: @Richard I tried to ping with port number (for example: `ping 35.193.35.4:80`). But it shows that `Ping request could not find host 35.193.35.4:80. Please check the name and try again`.

Comment: @SanniddhaChakrabarti Richard's answer is entirely correct. The service that you run on your machine called Apache is only a web server. The machine that runs that web server is still running even after you terminate the Apache process. The machine's Operating System is what responds to ping requests, not apache. You also cannot "ping" an address with a port number. It's only used to determine if a machine is able to be reached, not if a specific port can be reached.